# Can I add 100 Phone Numbers to a Single Contact?

Tags: iphone, contacts, caller-id

My bank insists on sending me account info SMS (texts) from ~100 different numbers. They all start the same, only the last two digits differ.

e.g.

- +43 664 6601301
- +43 664 6601302
- +43 664 6601303
- ...
- +43 664 6601399

Can I add all of them to a single contact? Preferably without having to type them separately.

I tried

- +43 664 66013
- +43 664 66013,
- +43 664 66013*
- +43 664 66013#
- +43 664 66013##

but the iPhone doesn't recognize any for the caller id.

Comment: The *-sign en #-sign could be use as part of a stored phone number. Thus they should not work as wildcards in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no reference to wildcard characters in vcard.

If Mac OS or iOS supported such feature it would not be supported by other devices.

But you can add the 100 phone numbers by hand. I would recommend exporting the contact as a vcd file then add all the numbers by hand. Copy paste will be faster than writing them one by one in the Contacts app:

```
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+43 664 6601301
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+43 664 6601302
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+43 664 6601303
...
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+43 664 6601399
```

And import it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently, but with 2000 phone numbers, so I wrote a small python script, [vcard-wildcard](https://github.com/jil24/vcard-wildcard), to generate vcards with multiple numbers based on a wildcard. Beware that attaching >100 numbers to a single vcard may cause your phone to become unresponsive for a while when you attempt to import the generated contact.

#### Example usage:

```
python vcard-wildcard.py --company "Robocallers" "(555) 555 55??" > bigcontact.vcf
```